# sublimetext実行

Tags: sublimetext

C 言語のプログラムを書いているのですが、実行速度が遅いです。早くする方法はないでしょうか？

`ctrl + b` で実行してます。hello と出力するプログラムでも 20 秒ほどかかることもあります。
また、 `cin` などで入力するプログラムだと、英文字がたくさん出てきて、入力できません。

使用している OS, エディタは、 Windows 10, Sublime Text 3 です。
ビルド番号はどこに書いてあるかわかりません。

入れているパッケージは

- sublimelinter-cppcheck
- sublimelinter
- package control
- origami
- material theme
- imesupport
- docblockr
- C++ sinppets
- BracketHighlighter
- BoundKeys
- Alignment
- AdvancedNewFile

です。

Comment: 具体的にどんな風に実行しているのか、手順を踏みつつご説明頂けますか？　通常そこまで遅くないので、もう少し情報を頂きたいです。コードが短いのであればそれも追記いただければと思います。質問文の下の「編集」から追記いただければと思います。

Comment: お使いの Windows は 10 でしょうか？　また、Sublime Text のバージョンは 2 でしょうか 3 でしょうか？　可能であれば Sublime Text のビルド番号も頂きたいです（原因の切り分けのためです）。

Comment: お使いの C コンパイラの詳細もあると嬉しいです。

Comment: タイトルも簡潔過ぎて意味するところが分からないのですが、こちらは「sublime text3上でプログラムを実行したときに遅い（他の方法なら問題ない）」という事を言っているのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、sublime text3上だけ遅いです。

Comment: また、ほかのパソコンを使うと早いのですがこのノートパソコン上のsublime test3上だけ遅いです。

Comment: @user28964 特定ＰＣだけ遅いとなると Windows Update の状況とかウイルス対策ソフトの違いとか、ＰＣ側の問題であろうと思われます。とりあえずプログラム開発に使っている作業ディレクトリをリアルタイム検索対象外に指定してみるとか。

Comment: ノートンを使っていますが、リアルタイム検索外にしてありました。